# Simple addition, multiplication, divison, and subtraction program

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, calculator

I made a post a couple of days ago asking if anyone noticed bad habits or thought of any suggestions: ([First Hangman game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/72193/first-hangman-game))

I've made 2 math programs just to make sure I got it all down pat. The first one (the subject of this question) is a simple addition, multiplication, division, and subtraction program that would deal out random numbers and ask you to add, sub, multiply, or divide them.

```
#12/14/14
import random

def choose():
    num1, num2 = pick_numbers()
    types = input("What type would you like Add, Sub, Mutl, Div?\n> ")
    if types.upper() == "ADD":
        print("Creating your addition problem...")
        print("{} + {}".format(num1, num2))
        correct_answer = num1 + num2
        return correct_answer
    elif types.upper() == "SUB":
        print("Creating your subtraction problem...")
        print("{} - {}".format(num1, num2))
        correct_answer = num1 - num2
        return correct_answer
    elif types.upper() == "MULT":
        print("Creating your mutliplecation problem...")
        print("{} * {}".format(num1, num2))
        correct_answer = num1 * num2
        return correct_answer
    elif types.upper() == "div":
        print("Creating your divison problem...")
        print("{} / {}".format(num1, num2))
        correct_answer = num1 / num2
        return correct_answer
    else:
        print("Error: Please only choose, add, sub, mult, or div")


def pick_numbers():
    num1 = random.randint(1, 100)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 100)
    return num1, num2

def print_problem():
    correct_answer = choose()
    while True:
        answer = input("What is your answer?\n> ")
        if(int(answer) == correct_answer):
            print("Correct! The answer was {}".format(answer))
            return False
        else:
            print("Sorry {} isn't correct.".format(answer))

def play_again():
    try_again = input("Would you like to play again?\n> ")
    if try_again.upper() == "Y":
        return True
    elif try_again.upper() == "N":
        return False
    else:
        print("Error: please choose only 'Y' or 'N'")

while True:
    print_problem()
    if not play_again():
        break
```

Do you still notice any bad habits or have any suggestions so I can have better structure or code organization?

Comment: I have removed the second part of this question. Please dig through the revision history, pull out that part, and post it as a second question. It would be best that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Be careful with exceptions. `int(answer)` may raise a `ValueError` if an answer cannot be converted. Same goes for unchecked division.
- In case of an illegal choice, `choose` doesn't return a value. Not a problem here, but rather a bad habit.
- `if/elif/elif/...` cascade is usually better expressed via a dictionary, in this case of 2-tuples (a format string and a lambda:

  ```
  problems = { "ADD": ("{} + {}", lambda x,y: x + y), 
               "MULT": (...),
                etc }
  ```

  Then the body of `choose` could be reduced to

  ```
  try:
      format, action = problems[types.upper()]
      print format.format(num1, num2)
      return action(num1, num2)
  except KeyError:
      print "Choose only from %s" % ",".join([key for key in problem.keys()])
  ```

  and you may freely add more operations to `problems` not ever touching the code.

Comment: Small improvement: `join` accepts a generator directly, so the `[`list comprehension`]` is superflous; in fact, the whole thing is unnecessary - `.join(problem.keys())` would suffice

Answer (score 2):

Just to point out a bug in your text processing. You convert all the operations to 'upper', but for division, you compare it to the lowercase value `... == "div"`. This will never match.

Your testing has not identified this problem, and it is a good reminder to have comprehensive tests, and to be careful with copy/paste.

Finally, the repeated use of `types.upper()` indicates that it should be stored in a variable, and reused.

Comment: Yes I fixed that in my code when I was testing it and I forgot to edit the post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A few minor points on top of the other reviews.

In `print_problem`, when the answer is correct, you `return True`,
but the return value of this method is never used.
It would be better to simply `return` (without arguments),
or even just to simply `break` to get out of the loop and let the method end normally.

To avoid the repetition of `.upper()` calls in here:

> ```
> if types.upper() == "ADD":
>     # ...
> elif types.upper() == "SUB":
>     # ...
> elif types.upper() == "MULT":
>     # ...
> ```

You could have done this:

```
types = input("What type would you like Add, Sub, Mutl, Div?\n> ").upper()
```

Actually, typing out `ADD`, `SUB`, ... is a bit harder than `add`, `sub`, ..., so instead of converting the input to upper and comparing with uppercase constants, I'd convert the input to lower and compare with lowercase constants.

In `play_again`, the last `else` statement is unnecessary, because the `if` and `elif` branches always `return`. In fact you could also replace the `elif` with an `if` for the same reason. Applying similar suggestions related to case conversion, the implementation becomes slightly simpler:

```
try_again = input("Would you like to play again?\n> ").lower()
if try_again == "y":
    return True
if try_again == "n":
    return False
print("Error: please enter 'Y' or 'N'")
```